# Uncaught TypeError in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'setTimeout' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function` Though function is going well in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. But Chrome is creating such problem. When I tried to trace out the code on respective line. I have following function in library.

```
// Animations created synchronously will run synchronously
function createFxNow() {
    setTimeout( clearFxNow, 0 ); // Line where I am getting error. 
    return ( fxNow = jQuery.now() );
}

function clearFxNow() {
fxNow = undefined;
}
```

Comment: check your code for strings like `setTimeout = something`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the global object isn't in scope here for some reason. Try using `window.setTimeout`. All "global" variables/functions should be referenced like this anyway.

BTW: the line `fxNow = undefined;` is dangerous. `undefined` is not a keyword in JavaScript, but just a variable that (usually) just happens to be undefined. If some other code sets it (`undefined = "Hello"`) you'll have a problem. `fxNow = null` is probably the better choice.

Comment: The `fxNow` is part of jQuery where `undefined` is a local variable that really is `undefined` due to no argument passed.

Comment: Changes make to library of Jquery doesn't help me to achieve requirements. Its continue with same error.

Comment: @Rahul: Maybe the function is being overwritten by another JavaScript? Use the debugger to check the value of `window.setTimeout`.